# Angular - Do We Need A Constructor If It Doesn't Have Any Logic

Tags: angular, constructor, angular9

I'm working with Angular.

I'm wondering about whether constructors are needed, and would appreciate some insight.
In several classes, I have constructor that are empty most of the time my service classes have empty constructors.

Can these empty constructors be removed? Are there any negative impact to a class have no constructor vs having an empty one?

Comment: If your constructor is empty and has no parameters, you can safely remove it. If it has parameters declared as `public` or `private` those parameters are also member variables, in which case you might not be able to remove it - it depends on the rest of the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't use DI (dependency injection) service for Angular in your class you can remove it .

If the class won't be used by third parties and you don't need an overloaded constructor, don't write an empty constructor.